# data.table order vs setorder: copy vs reference

Tags: r, data.table

From `data.table`'s [documentation](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/setorder.html) for ordering rows of a table:

> It reorders the table by reference and is therefore very memory efficient.

Using `setorder`, we get the expected behavior from the documentation (rows are ordered by reference):

```
x <- data.table(col = c(3,2,1))
all(setorder(x, col) == x)
> TRUE
```

However, using `[` and `order` yields a copy:

```
x <- data.table(col = c(3,2,1))
all(x[order(col)] == x)
> FALSE
```

In the second case, `x` is being copied and ordered, so the comparison versus the original fails.

**Question:** Is this behavior expected and is `data.table`'s documentation incomplete?

Comment: The part of the documentation you've quoted is specifically for `setorder()`, and not `order()`. All the `set` functions in data.table are "by-reference". So I think the documentation is fine.

Comment: This behaviour is expected. Can you explain where you think the documentation is lacking?

Comment: @sindri_baldur @tospig Thanks for the comments. I got confused because `order` is mentioned in `setorder` documentation. Having an explicit comment about how `order` differs from `setorder` in that page would make things more transparent.